# extend /home partion with available unallocated

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I tried to extend the disk space of /home with the unallocated space. I also refered to some solutions present online, but unable to follow.
How I can merge the unallocated space with /home?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before doing anything, **BACKUP FIRST**!

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB flash, and start `gparted`.

In gparted, you can **create/delete/move/resize** partitions. *(There is no such thing as **merge**)*. In your case, **move** is done by dragging whole partitions *(or changing numerical values)*, and **resize** is done by dragging the partitions **right**-edge handle *(or changing numerical values)*. **Never** resize NTFS partitions using gparted... always use Windows own Disk Management application.

To proceed, do the following (do these commands one at a time by clicking the **apply** checkmark after each command, **don't** stack commands):

```
1. move sda6 all the way left
2. move sda7 all the way left
3. move sda9 all the way left
4. move sda10 all the way left
5. resize sda10 maximum to the right
```

Once done, in terminal, type `sudo fdisk -l` *(lower case L)*, or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` *(lower case L)*, and make sure that you don't have any partition alignment problems.

Questions? Problems? Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al

Comment: Ubuntu live DVD means bootable flash drive, right??

Comment: @Tetragrammaton Yes, it's effectively the same thing.

Comment: Where shld I use the terminal, on live USB or after rebooting in os??

Comment: Either one. Edit the output into your question so I can take a look. Let us know your final result... success? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Why are you adding "Cheers, Al" at the end of all your comments?

Comment: @Anwar to personalize my comments/answers, and to sound less computerized, and so they can refer to me by name if desired.

Comment: @heynnema for me, it is more computerized and less friendly. honestly speaking

Comment: @heynnema final result  :- success

Comment: Great news! Lets see the output of the fdisk/gdisk commands that I gave you. Just edit the output into your question. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 2):

Based of the information provided by you-you have only one hard drive(/dev/sda)
You need to make sure that /home which is 38.32 GB next(contiguos) to the unallocated(39.29) then only you can merge that 39.29 to the /home.

Please refer to gparted documentation to try that out.

Please remember you cannot edit your partition if the partition is currently being used. Perform the operation from a "live" disk or USB?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your partition table you have 2 choices.
1) move your windows partitions towards the unallocated space as suggested by heynnema.
This will take a long time to finish and has the potential to mess with your windows install.

2) create an ext4 partition from the unallocated space and create symbolic links.
If you are using an encrypted home drive you can "extend" your home partition using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103835/securely-automount-encrypted-drive-at-user-login/165451#165451).

You might also set up a raid system (although I do not recommend this especially since both "volumes" are on the same disk.....)

I, personally, would use symbolic links (I am currently using symbolic links to link 3 HDD's together) or I would simply reinstall my system. This is due to the sheer amount of data that needs to be moved (nearly 450 gb) to move these partitions next to each other

Comment: You make some good points, however... the two ntfs partitions that need to get moved are not Windows OS partitions, and, the actual amount of *data* to get moved is around 317G. And that's why my first instruction says **backup**. Cheers, Al